# Fixing a function to run for x:y instead of only 1:y

Tags: r, function, plot, error-handling

I have defined a function to calculate the relationship between height (h) and diameter (dbh) of trees based on equations extracted from 2 publications. My goal is to use the relationship established in paper 1 (Xiangtao) to predict the values of variables in an equation in paper 2 (Marechaux and Chave). I would like to test to see over what diameter range `[x:y]` the generated `nls()` curve of paper 2 fits paper 1. Currently, I keep getting an error (I believe in `plot()`)

`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :`
  `'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

if I use anything except x=1 for `[x:y]` i.e. `dbh.min:dbh.max`

My function is as follows:

```
# Plant.Functional.Type constants...
Dsb1 <- 2.09
Dsb2 <- 0.54
Db1 <- 0.93
Db2 <- 0.84
BDb1 <- 2.66
BDb2 <- 0.48
Eb1 <- 1.41
Eb2 <- 0.65
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
Generate.curve <- function(b1, b2, dbh.min, dbh.max){
# calculate Xiangtao's allometry...
  tmp_h <- c(dbh.min:dbh.max)
  for (dbh in dbh.min:dbh.max)
  {
    h = b1*dbh^(b2)
    tmp_h[dbh] = h
  }
# plot to check curve
  plot(dbh.min:dbh.max, tmp_h)

# define secondary function for Marechaux and Chave allometry
  h_fxn <- function(hlim,dbh,ah){
    h = hlim * (dbh / (dbh + ah))
    return(h)
  }

# use nonlinear least squares model to solve for ah and hlim
  # set model inputs
  start.ah <- 1 
  start.hlim <- 5
  tmp_v <- cbind(dbh.min:dbh.max,tmp_h)

tmp.fit <- nls(tmp_h ~ h_fxn(hlim,dbh.min:dbh.max,ah), start = list(hlim = start.hlim, 
                ah = start.ah), algorithm = "port", upper = list(hlim = 75, ah = 99))  
# seems to be no way of extracting ah and hlim from tmp.fit via subset
# extract manually and then check fit with
  # lines(dbh.min:dbh.max, hlim * (dbh.min:dbh.max/(dbh.min:dbh.max + ah)))
  # for equation h = hlim * (dbh / (dbh + ah)) from Marechaux and Chave
return(tmp.fit)
}
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

This works great for

```
Generate.curve(Dsb1,Dsb2,1,100)
lines(1:100, 36.75 * (1:100/(1:100 + 52.51)))
```

But I would like to be able to examine the curve fit in ranges such as `[80:100]` as well.
I have been trying to figure out why `Generate.curve(Dsb1,Dsb2,80,100)` returns an error for about 3 days now. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this section:

```r
  tmp_h <- c(dbh.min:dbh.max)
  for (dbh in dbh.min:dbh.max)
  {
    h = b1*dbh^(b2)
    tmp_h[dbh] = h
  }
```

Think about what happens when you set `dbh.min` to 80 and `dbh.max` to 100:

```r
  tmp_h <- 80:100
  for (dbh in 80:100)
  {
    h = b1*dbh^(b2)
    tmp_h[dbh] = h
  }
```

What happens on the first cycle of the loop? Well, `tmp_h` is length 20, but on the first cycle, `dbh` is 80, and you are assigning a number to `tmp_h[dbh]`, which is `tmp_h[80]`. By the time the loop has finished, `tmp_h` will have the correct values stored, but they will be in the indices `80:100`. So `tmp_h` will have the numbers 80:100 stored in the first 21 indices, then a bunch of NAs then the correct numbers in the last 21 indices.

So change it to:

```r
  tmp_h <- c(dbh.min:dbh.max)
  for (dbh in dbh.min:dbh.max)
  {
    h = b1*dbh^(b2)
    tmp_h[dbh - dbh.min + 1] = h
  }
```

and it will work.

However, you don't actually need a loop at all here, since R uses vectorized operations, so this whole section can be replaced with:

```r
tmp_h <- b1 * (dbh.min:dbh.max)^(b2)
```

and then when you do

```r
Generate.curve(Dsb1,Dsb2,80,100)
lines(80:100, 36.75 * (80:100/(80:100 + 52.51)))
```

you get this:

[image]

Comment: This is less important, as I can still in general get the information I need, but when I run with dbhmin and dbhmax at a certain distance from one another, e.g. ```Generate.curve(Dsb1,Dsb2,40,80)``` I get ```Error in nls(tmp_h ~ h_fxn(hlim, dbh.min:dbh.max, ah), start = list(hlim = start.hlim,  : 
  Convergence failure: false convergence (8)```
Any idea why?

Comment: @sethparker I think it's simply because you can't fit the model with too few data points.